# Vertical space between toc title and the following entry

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to reduce the vertical space only between the TOC title ("Contents") and the following entry ("1 Intro to Science") in half. Similarly for the "List of Figures" and "List of tables"

Here is a MWE. Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=4cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm]{geometry}      % Easily set margins
\usepackage[toc,title,page]{appendix}                 % Configure appendix formatting
\usepackage{tocloft}                  

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage   
\chapter{Intro to Science }
\section{A}
\section{B}

\chapter{Intro to Math }
\section{A}
\section{B}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty: Add a negative `\vspace` to the ToC:

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=4cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm]{geometry}      % Easily set margins
\usepackage[toc,title,page]{appendix}                 % Configure appendix formatting
\usepackage{tocloft}                  


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace*{-7ex}}%
\clearpage   
\chapter{Intro to Science }
\section{A}
\section{B}

\chapter{Intro to Math }
\section{A}
\section{B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works only for the contents but how to change for the "list of figures" and "list of tables" in a similar fashion?

Comment: @Paul `\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace*{-7ex}}` and `\addtocontents{lot}{\vspace*{-7ex}}`.